# polling with jboss

Tags: java, jboss, polling

I want to deploy a Java application on JBOSS  that starts after deploy, writes a text row in a file after every 'X' seconds and stops when JBOSS stops.

I know how to create a runnable jar but I've no idea how to create a war file in jboss.

```
while(true){
    count ++;
    System.out.println("Hello - " + count);
    Thread.sleep(this.properties.getSleep_time() *1000);
}
```

I've already written a method that polls a database table every 10 seconds, and it's working fine. I've embedded it into a servlet just to deploy it on jboss (using init method and timers). All works fine except when JBOSS shut down, because it can't undeploy my servlet. Is it ok to use a servlet for polling purpose?

Comment: I've just consult big G but i've not find anything that could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve my problem by insert this 2 methods inside my servle:

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    // Do your job here during webapp startup.
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    // Do your job here during webapp shutdown.
}
```

So when **contextDestroyed** is called I stop the polling scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to start with the [Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) to know what Java EE (like JBoss As) is.

The [timer service](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html) is the part you need to look at for tack scheduling (Spec put a "shouldn't" with any thread manipulation. (tip: use manual trigger over `@Schedule` if the process duration can be similar to the tick time)

Your question realy trigger some alarm, you should look at the Java EE tutorial and other Java EE documentation to assess if Java EE is a correct solution for your application.

Comment: The tutorial section on [Using the Timer Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html) seems particularly relevant.

Comment: Do you think the question suggests that Java EE isn't the right solution? Plenty of people run scheduled jobs in application servers, and this seems like a case of that.

Comment: If you need fine thread management, Java EE won't fit.  But if you only need job scheduling it should be ok.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, maybe i didn't explain myself.
I've already written a method that polls a database table every 10 seconds, and it's working fine. I've embedded it into a servlet just to deploy it on jboss (using init method and timers). All works fine except when JBOSS shut down, because it can't undeploy my servlet. Is it ok to use a servlet for polling purpose?

Comment: This is the reason direct thread manipulation is not recomended in a application server, there is no way for the app server to manage them.  If you manage your thread in a `ServletContextListener` (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) you should able to kill the thread you self when the servlet in undeployed.